# Extract metadata from RDMS using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata, python-2.x

I have a use-case where I've multiple `RDMS data-sources` and I want to extract the `metadata` from those `data-sources`. On the Basis of `lookup` user will select the `data-source` type and make the connection. After a successful connection, the tables and columns details will be populated.

As I'm a newbie with Python, I came with a solution to write code with conditional statements and make the connection accordingly. But I believe this is not the best and appropriate solution because for every new `data-source` I've to make the changes in code.

I'm looking for some ideas/suggestions through which I could archive some dynamic behavior. Like `dialects` available in `ORM` tools or some library which will execute the same query for all `data-source` types.

I appreciate your ideas/suggestions.

Comment: If you show some skeleton code or pseudocode, people will be more inclined to help. Just posting a requirements dump then asking for package recommendations is considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For example, your choice of GUI is separate and not relevant to this question.

Comment: @smci thanks for hitting me back, I'm currently looking for recommendations and best practices so that I would RnD that in right direction. The above mentioned is one of the use-case which we wanted to implement which is currently on papers.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you your question is likely to get quickly downvoted and/or closed unless you show a little code/pseudocode. And remove the GUI mentions.